# How to get an XML report from JIRA by program?

Tags: java, xml, curl, jira

I can get a JSON-formatted report from JIRA by using a cURL command from Java :

```
public InputStream getUserData( String userName, String filter ) throws IOException
{
  Process process = new ProcessBuilder( CURLEXE_PATH, "-D-", "-u", "<username>:<password>", "-X", "GET", "-H",
    "\"Content-Type: application/json\"", "\"" + JIRA_URL + "?jql=assignee=" + userName + "&" + filter
        + "\"" ).start();
  return process.getInputStream();
}
```

The above code works fine, but I would like to get the filtered JIRA report in XML. Can you please help me on this? I don't want to spend time learning the REST API. I want a simple thing to help a colleague collecting time spent on tasks for reporting purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to learn the JIRA REST API. Go to JIRA, Issues, Search and create a search for the issues you want to return. Then find the chain icon and copy the URL for the search from there. Replace the query in your String above and it should just work.

Comment: Yes, I know this mechanism and that's the way I have built my HTTP request. My question is about getting results in XML rather than JSON.

Comment: Let's forget the XML output. I will use GSON, the JSON parser from Google. Thanks a lot for your time!